# Trying to debug GearVR(native) without having to insert it into the device("You are not a developer")

Tags: android-studio, signature, oculus, gear-vr

I am trying to debug my GearVR app(just building one of the samples actually) on my Galaxy S7 but when running a GearVR app the device usually require you to connect it to the GearVR goggles.
Here is the page explaining how I am suppose to become an oculus developer on my own device.

https://developer.oculus.com/osig/

I acquired the signature for my device and put the file in the assets of the app.
However, when I run it it still asks for it to be connected to GearVR.
When I try the "trick" to become an oculus developer it says "You are not a developer"(kind of insulting to be honest... :P)
The way to become a developer is to go to the GearVR app and then in Storage tap several time on the VR service number.
But before it unlocks you need to successfuly run a osig signed app on the gear VR?
So I am not sure what I am doing wrong right now and how to make it work.

Comment: You need to do the drill of running a sample app and inserting it in the GearVR at least once before you can unlock dev mode. If you don't have a GearVR at all I'm afraid you are out of luck. Without it you will not have any head tracking anyway as it won't use the phone internal gyro.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the issue is that I wrote "cd" instead of "ce" in the device ID when trying to generate my osig.
In addition, I installed my app using adb instead of Android Studio because I generated a signed APK.
However, I generated a debug signed APK instead of a release signed APK.
After install my release signed apk with the correct osig in the assets and running it and then connecting it to GearVR it ran without errors and I was able to become a GearVR developer.

Comment: Why did someone downvote this? This kind of issue happened to me once and I also did not have any idea what happened (mine was a copy-pase without one letter)

Answer (score 0):

[From the Oculus developer documentation](https://developer3.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/latest/concepts/mobile-troublesh-device-run-app-outside/)

> Note: Before enabling Developer Mode, you must have previously built
>   an apk signed with your osig file and installed it to your device.
>   Otherwise, you will see an error message saying "You are not a
>   developer!"

I would like to point out that "signed with your osig file" means to put it in the assets folder of your application. On top of that you want to sign it as a regular Android app.

Getting the osig file is a matter of running "adb devices" get the id and go to [Oculus osig generator](https://dashboard.oculus.com/tools/osig-generator/)